# Empty results when the query uses SELECT * - The weird thing ever

Tags: mysql

I'm facing and weird issue with a query, I never saw something like this in more than 10 years developing.

A **InnoDB** table with 8M of rows, this table is used to store references between 2 other tables (pages and keywords)

```
| Field           | Type                | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| page_id         | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | 0                   |                |
| keyword_id      | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | 0                   |                |
| avg_kc          | tinyint(3)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| rank_on_page    | tinyint(2)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at      | timestamp           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| updated_at      | timestamp           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

The issue is, if you use `SELECT *` returns an `Empty set`

```
mysql> select * from pages_metrics where keyword_id=2385 and page_id=6004 ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

But, if you select only some fields the query runs well.

```
mysql> select id, page_id, keyword_id from pages_metrics where keyword_id=2385 and page_id=6004;
+---------+---------+------------+
| id      | page_id | keyword_id |
+---------+---------+------------+
| 8469199 |    6004 |       2385 |
+---------+---------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I run the `analyze table` and all looks good.

```
mysql> analyze table pages_metrics;
+------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| Table                  | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| keywords.pages_metrics | analyze | status   | OK       |
+------------------------+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.34 sec)
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's myIsam or InnoDB?

Comment: I forgot that, it's a InnoDB table, I add that to the main question.

Comment: Also, try to "analyze table" (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html)

Comment: And make sure you have commited your data.

Comment: This isn't the weirdest thing ever. See for instance Donald Trump's hair.

Comment: The `analyze table` command returns an `OK` status

Comment: What happens if you explicitly list all of the fields in the SELECT list? If that results in an empty set, can you try removing fields until you find the one that breaks the query?